# Get the Period between two local date instances like P1Y2M10DT2H30M

Tags: java-8, period

How can I obtain the `Period` between two different `LocalDate` instances using Java.

I googled, not able to find it.

Comment: What you need to do exactly? Get the period between different dates.

Comment: When Google has such an extraordinarily poor day there is no other resort than [RTFM, read the friendly manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) (a less nice interpretation of the abbreviation also exists). [Tutorial section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Period` is the amount of time between two `LocalDate`. Same concept as `Duration`. Here's the difference between the two: A `Duration` measures an amount of time using time-based values (seconds, nanoseconds). A `Period` uses date-based values (years, months, days). However, using `Period` you can't get the hours, mins as you mentioned in the problem statement above.

Comment: I want only Years, Months and Days that's Period. I Understood the concepts of Duration and Period concept. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I got it.

```
LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.of(2010, 5, 17); // 2010-05-17
LocalDate secondDate = LocalDate.of(2015, 3, 7); // 2015-03-07
Period period = Period.between(firstDate, secondDate);
System.out.println(period); //P4Y9M18D
```